# Made a game like Subway Surfers, but the character stutters/vibrates on lane movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a game like Subway Surfers. The game runs fine when on the Unit Editor, but when I export it into an apk and play it on mobile, the character vibrates when I move left and right.
I did not add any Rigidbodies instead, I added a character controller.

This is the player movement code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PLAYERLANEMOV : MonoBehaviour
{
    public const float LANE_DISTANCE = 2.5f;
    private const float TURN_SPEED = 0.5f;

    //
    private bool isRunning = false;

    //animation 

    private Animator anim;
    // movement 
    private CharacterController controller;
    private float jumbForce = 10.0f;
    private float gravity = 12.0f;
    private float verticalVelocity;
   
    private int desiredLane = 1; // 0=left , 1 = center ,2 = right 

    //speed modifier
    private float originalSpeed = 7.0f;
    private float speed = 7.0f;
    private float speedIncreaseLastTick;
    private float speedIncreaseTime = 2.5f;
    private float speedIncreaseAmount = 0.1f;

    private void Start()
    {
        speed = originalSpeed;
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {

        if (!isRunning)
            return;

        if (Time.time - speedIncreaseLastTick > speedIncreaseTime)
        {
            speedIncreaseLastTick = Time.time;
            speed += speedIncreaseAmount;
            GameManager.Instance.UpdateModifier(speed - originalSpeed);
        }


        if (MobileInput.Instance.SwipeLeft)
            MoveLane(false);
        if (MobileInput.Instance.SwipeRight)
            MoveLane(true);

        Vector3 targetPosition = transform.position.z * Vector3.forward;
        if (desiredLane == 0)
            targetPosition += Vector3.left * LANE_DISTANCE;
        else if (desiredLane == 2)
            targetPosition += Vector3.right * LANE_DISTANCE;

        Vector3 moveVector = Vector3.zero;
        moveVector.x = (targetPosition - transform.position).normalized.x * speed;

        bool isGrounded = IsGrounded();
        anim.SetBool("Grounded", isGrounded);
        //gravity
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            verticalVelocity = 0f;
            

            if (MobileInput.Instance.SwipeUp)
            {
                //jumb
                anim.SetTrigger("Jump");
                verticalVelocity = jumbForce;
            }
            else if (MobileInput.Instance.SwipeDown)
            {
                //slide
                StartSliding();
                Invoke("StopSliding", 1.0f);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            verticalVelocity -= (gravity * Time.deltaTime);

            //fast falling
            if (MobileInput.Instance.SwipeDown)
            {
                verticalVelocity = -jumbForce;
            }
        }
        moveVector.y = verticalVelocity;
        moveVector.z = speed;

        controller.Move(moveVector * Time.deltaTime);

        //rotate to where he is going
       // Vector3 dir = controller.velocity;
       // if (dir != Vector3.zero)
       // {
      //      dir.y = 0;
      //      transform.forward = Vector3.Lerp(transform.forward, dir, TURN_SPEED);
     //  }
    }

    private void StartSliding()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Sliding", true);
        controller.height /= 2;
        controller.center = new Vector3(controller.center.x, controller.center.y / 2, controller.center.z);
    }

    private void StopSliding()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Sliding", false);
        controller.height *= 2;
        controller.center = new Vector3(controller.center.x, controller.center.y * 2, controller.center.z);
    }

    private void MoveLane(bool goingRight)
    {
        desiredLane += (goingRight) ? 1 : -1;
        desiredLane = Mathf.Clamp(desiredLane, 0, 2);
    }

    bool IsGrounded()
        {
            Ray groundRay = new Ray(
                new Vector3(
                    controller.bounds.center.x,
                    (controller.bounds.center.y - controller.bounds.extents.y) + 0.2f,
                    controller.bounds.center.z),
                Vector3.down);
            Debug.DrawRay(groundRay.origin, groundRay.direction, Color.cyan, 1.0f);

        return Physics.Raycast(groundRay, 0.2f + 0.1f); ;

    }

    public void StartRunning()
    {
        isRunning = true;
        anim.SetTrigger("StartRunning");
    } 

    private void Crash()
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("Death");
        isRunning = false;
        GameManager.Instance.OnDeath();
    }

    private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        switch (hit.gameObject.tag)
        {
            case "Obstacle":
                Crash();
                break;
        }
    }


}
```

This is camera movement code:

```
   using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CAMERAFOLLO : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform lookAt;// our charcter we are looking at 
    public Vector3 offset = new Vector3( 3.0f, -3.0f);
    public Vector3 rotation = new Vector3(35, 0, 0);

    public bool IsMoving { set; get; }


    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (!IsMoving)
            return;

        Vector3 desiredPosition = lookAt.position + offset;
       // desiredPosition.x = 0;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition,0.1f);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation,Quaternion.Euler(rotation),Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aravind, I'd add more detail about what the movement differences are when you export to APK, and more detail about the game besides that it's "like subwaysurfers".

I'd also mention version numbers of everything including what android version you're running, since that may identify the issue between running the game locally and on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

`Camera` and `GameObject` stuttering is often caused by a [mis-match of `Update` calls.](https://forum.unity.com/threads/character-in-fixedupdate-and-camera-in-lateupdate-jitter-problem.380560/)

Generally you should move your camera in `LateUpdate` and perform frame-rate independent things, like movement of the player, in [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html).

Try changing `private void LateUpdate()` to `private void FixedUpdate()` in the `PLAYERLANEMOV` class.

Don't forget when you work with different `Update` calls such as `void Update` and `void FixedUpdate` you should use the correct time-interval for each, since they both use different time-steps between their calls. For `void Update` this would be `Time.deltaTime` and for `void FixedUpdate` it would be [`Time.fixedDeltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html)